# can't get transfer to execute

Tags: solidity, ether, balances, payable, address.transfer

I am trying to run the following solidity function:

```
function test() payable {
msg.sender.transfer((balances[msg.sender]/1000)*this.balance);
}
```

Where `this.balance` is 0.1 Ether and `balances[msg.sender]` is 200, so the `msg.sender` should be sent 0.02 Ether. However, this never works. I have tried executing the function in the following ways (sending ether or not, it doesn't execute the transfer):

```
contract.test({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas:1000000, value: web3.toWei(0.01, "ether")})
contract.test({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas:1000000})
```

I have verified the values of `balances[msg.sender]` and `this.balance` as follows (I'm using the same `msg.sender` account in all cases):

```
function balance() constant returns (uint256) {
           return balances[msg.sender];
       }

 function contractBalance() returns (uint256) {
           return this.balance;
       }
```

Comment: Is balances[msg.sender] 200 wei or 200 * ETH_TO_WEI? If it's the former your contract will be rounding it down to 0. It's better to so the multiplication first, then divide the bigger number by 1000.

Comment: balances[msg.sender] is generated when the user submits ether to the contract, and is basically balances[msg.sender] = (msg.value)*(1000)/10**18 so I think that's the issue I overlooked. The function where it does msg.sender.transfer also has other code in it which runs, so I think msg.sender.transfer is going through but transferring nothing (I believe it msg.sender.transfer in a function fails, none of the code in that function will go through).

Comment: OK, so as well as multiplying first, don't try to convert to ETH in the contract. Do everything in Wei, then convert to and from ETH in the UI.